# Add to Google Wallet button is not working inside iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, google-wallet

I am working on a project that is embedded in some other sites via iframe. I want to implement Google Wallet in my project. I followed the documentation and Implemented the 'Add to Google Wallet' button, it worked perfectly in my project when it was not invoked inside an iframe. But inside the iframe, button is not working, I got an error code while clicking the button (SERVICE_ERROR)

I implemented the Google Wallet button using 'gapi.savetoandroidpay.render' function. I need the 'Add to Google wallet' feature inside my site when it is embedded on other sites via iframe

[Button text is turned to 'Error' when clicking inside iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEvxO.png)